# Can i integrate selenium webdriver with rest assured

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario as given below,

1. i opened the browser and opened the url using selenium webdriver
2. Now i wanted to create an account using REST API using rest assured
3. Use those account credentials that were created using REST API using REST ASSSURED to login to the web app using web driver.

To implement the above, Is it mandatory to create a maven project and add rest assured dependencies in POM.xml? are there other ways to implement these? What all libraries or prerequisites, etc are required for me to set up environment to integrate both selenium and  Rest assured?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an account you probably want to extract the session from rest assured and supply it to web driver. From rest assured you can extract the session like this:

String sessionId = given().. .post("/login").then().extract().sessionId();

You don't need to create a maven (or gradle) project but it'll certainly help. I don't know about selenium but if you look at the [download page](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads) of rest assured you can download zip files including all its dependencies.